# Why use the uppercase key when creating association model in Sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have two model User and Post, defined the associated model as below:

```
Post.belongsTo(models.User)
```

It means Post model belongs to User as well as User has many Post. So the posts table in database must have the key userId for this association.

I create the Post assigned to user using this code:

```
Post.create({
    UserId: 1,
})
```

It would insert the right data to database.

But It's not work as I change the code:

```
Post.create({
    userId: 1,
})
```

Why the model use the uppercase UserId instead of userId ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you don't define the column on your model, the association fields are going to be generated taking the name of the model and adding the `Id` at the end. You can define the name of your models lower case, or define the foreign fields like this:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Post = sequelize.define('Post', {
    //
    userId: { //this is how you are going to use it on sequelize
      field: 'user_id', // this is how is goig to save it on the db, underscore for example
      type: DataTypes.DATE
    },
  });

  Post.associate = (models) => {
    Post.belongsTo(models.User, { as: 'User', foreignKey: 'user_id' });
  };

  return Post;
};
```

Comment: For me I was struggling until I realized I had to add the `foreignKey: 'user_id'` to both the belongsTo AND the hasMany in my case. Hope this helps!

Comment: The whole documentation does use lowercase names for columns and then the lib itself creates uppercase names for foreign keys. Isn't that a little bit strange?